# Can the parameter $t$ in the exponential map $e^{tX}$ be complex?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

From a Lie algebra to a Lie group, can the parameter $t$ in the exponential map $t\rightarrow e^{tX}$ be complex?

If the Lie algebra is a complex one, this is legal, right?

Comment: Is the Lie Group a complex Lie Group?

Comment: If the Lie algebra is a complex Lie algebra, then for any $X$ in the Lie algebra and any complex $t$, $tX$ is again a member of the Lie algebra, so yes. Otherwise it's unclear what you even mean by $tX$.